# How to remove data-mce-style inside of an element, using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

`$(editor[i])[0].outerHTML` has a value of:

```
 <p style="color: red;" data-mce-style="color: red;">some string</p>
```

I want `data-mce-style="color: red;"` to disappear.
I'm doing that like this:

```
$(editor[i])[0].outerHTML.replace('data-mce-style="color: red;"', '');
```

But it's not replacing it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`.replace` creates a *new* transformed string; it does not alter the original variable. You're simply creating a new string and not storing the new string back into `outerHTML`, like:

```
$(editor[i])[0].outerHTML = $(editor[i])[0].outerHTML.replace('data-mce-style="color: red;"', '');
```

However, this only solves your immediate problem -- there are vastly better ways to accomplish what you need than stringifying and re-parsing your `<p>` element. Since you're using jQuery, the most obvious way would be to use the [`removeAttr`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) method:

```
$(editor[i]).removeAttr('data-mce-style')​;​
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$(editor[i]).removeAttr('data-mce-style')
```

http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

Of course this will apply to all elements in your selector.  If you just want to apply this to element 0 then use:

```
$(editor[i]).first().removeAttr('data-mce-style')
```

Answer (score 1):

[element.setAttribute(attr, null)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.setAttribute)
or
[element.removeAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.removeAttribute)

No need for outerHTML and replace. Note that replacing HTML will remove event listeners (other than attribute event handlers).

Answer (score 1):

```
$(editor[i]).removeAttr('data-mce-style')​;​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/8FERC/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jQuery `removeData()`:

```
$(editor[i]).removeData('mce-style');
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to change/remove a particular attribute, for that you need to use

```
$(editor[i]).removeAttr('data-mce-style');
```

for more info check the following links:
http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

if you need to change the value of a particular attribute then do:

```
attr(attributeName, value);
```

for more info about the same check the following link:
http://api.jquery.com/attr/